# save current user location to firestore database?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, geofencing

```
TextEditingController location = TextEditingController();
Position? position;
List<Placemark>? placeMarks;
late LocationPermission permission;

getCurrentLocation() async // here is to fetch the user's location
 {
   LocationPermission allow = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
   Position newPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
     desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, 
   );

   position = newPosition;
   placeMarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
       position!.latitude,
       position!.longitude,
   ); 

Placemark pMark = placeMarks![0];
   String completeAddress = '${pMark.subThoroughfare} ${pMark.thoroughfare}, '
       '${pMark.subLocality} ${pMark.locality}, ${pMark.subAdministrativeArea}, '
       '${pMark.administrativeArea} ${pMark.postalCode}, ${pMark.country}'; // get exact location with state,country,postal

   location.text = completeAddress;
 }
```

i don't know how to save current user's location to firestore database so that i can use the id. Please help me

Comment: Writing data to Firestore is quite well documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data), and the code you shared doesn't call any of the APIs mentioned there. Unless you can show what you already tried to write to Firestore, it's unlikely we can explain it better than the documentation does.

Comment: how to add API?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#dart?